# Как создать кнопку для закрытия модального окна

Tags: javascript, css

Создал модальное окно , как закрыть его написав функцию на javascript-e . Html код должен быть приписан на 14 строчке

```css
<style type="text/css">.Window {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 99999;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.Window:target {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.Window>div {
  width: 1030px;
  height: 640px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: url("images/background.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-position: 74px -50px;
  background-size: 925px 640px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px;
  background-color: white;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  top: 7px;
  left: 992px;
}

.share {
  position: absolute;
  right-12px;
  top: 52px;
  left: 992px;
}

.fbshare {
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  top: 509px;
  left: 992px;
}

.twshare {
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  top: 546px;
  left: 992px;
}

a {
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.leftcol {
  width: 200px;
  height: 590px;
  float: left;
  background: url("images/lcolb.jpg") no-repeat;
}

.rigcol {
  width: 45px;
  height: 590px;
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 600px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 1030px;
  height: 50px;
}

.learn {
  position: relative;
  top: -58px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #0066cc;
  float: right;
}

.learnT {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.learn:hover {
  background: #3399FF;
}

.learn:hover a {
  color: #fff
}

hr {
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 462px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  border: 0;
}

.Tfind {
  margin-top: 477px;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.Thorizont {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  left: 211px;
  color: white;
}

.hr2 {
  width: 1px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  left: 438px;
  top: 600px;
}

.img1 {
  margin-left: 86px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.img1 {
  margin-left: 46px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.img2 {
  margin-top: 89px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.videocontent {
  width: 785px;
  height: 443px;
  margin-top: 107px;
}

</style>
```

```html
  <a href="#ModalOpen" title=""><img src="images/ban.jpg"></a>
  <div id="ModalOpen" class="Window">
    <div class="content">
      <video class="videocontent" controls poster="images/preview.jpg">
        <source src="images/ps.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
      </video>
      <div class="leftcol">
        <img class="img1" src="images/ps4.jpg">
        <img class="img2" src="images/logo.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="rigcol">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" id="modal_close">
          <img src="images/x.jpg">
        </button>
        <a href="#share" class="share">
          <img src="images/share.jpg">
        </a>
        <hr>
        <p class="Tfind"> Find
          <br/>US ON</p>
        </hr>
        <a href="#fb" class="fbshare">
          <img src="images/fb.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="#twitter" class="twshare">
          <img src="images/twit.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <img src="images/i.jpg" class="img1">
        <hr class="hr2">
        <p class="Thorizont">Click on Horizon Zero Dawn to see the next era of mankind</p>
        <div class="learn">
          <p class="learnT"><a href="#learnmore">Learn More  ></a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('your-button-selector')[0].onclick = function () {document.getElementById('ModalOpen').style.display = 'none';}` если без jQuery

Comment: где это нужно написать и что значит 'your-button-selector'

Comment: селектор твоей кнопки. в файле .js  или поместив скрипт в теги <script></script> и разместить где-то в футере этот скрипт

Comment: и какой же селектор нужно прописать ?

Comment: btn-close этот наверное или какой тебе нужен

Comment: <script>
  document.getElementsByClassName('btn-close')[0].o‌​nclick = function () {document.getElementById('ModalOpen').style.display = 'none';}
 </script>

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn-close" id="closeModal">
     <img src="images/x.jpg">
    </button>

Comment: да, так и нужно

Answer (score 2):

Можно к кнопке добавить обработчик, который будет вызываться по клику:

```js
function closeModal(){
  var modal = document.getElementById('ModalOpen');
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

function shwoModal(){
  var modal = document.getElementById('ModalOpen');
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div id="ModalOpen" class="Window">
 <span>Я внутри модалки(див) и тут еще может быть много всего</span>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" id="modal_close" onclick="closeModal();">Мы скрываемся</button>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn-close" id="modal_close" onclick="shwoModal();">Я верну тебя</button>
```

Если хотите с помощью `jQuery`, то скрывать можно так, без `getElementById`:

```js
function closeModal(){
  $('#ModalOpen').hide(); 
}

function shwoModal(){
  $('#ModalOpen').show(); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ModalOpen" class="Window">
 <span>Я внутри модалки(див) и тут еще может быть много всего</span>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" id="modal_close" onclick="closeModal();">Мы скрываемся</button>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn-close" id="modal_close" onclick="shwoModal();">Я верну тебя</button>
```

Для Вашей ситуации достаточно сделать вот так:

```
<a href="#ModalOpen" title="" onclick="shwoModal();"><img src="images/ban.jpg"></a>
```

ну и в кнопку закрытия прикрутите `onclick="closeModal();"` и все будет работать. И не забыть добавить `JavaScript` в котором описаны функции. Как-то так:

```js
function closeModal() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('ModalOpen');
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

function shwoModal() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('ModalOpen');
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.Window {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 99999;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.Window:target {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.Window>div {
  width: 1030px;
  height: 640px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: url("images/background.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-position: 74px -50px;
  background-size: 925px 640px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px;
  background-color: white;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  top: 7px;
  left: 992px;
}

.share {
  position: absolute;
  right-12px;
  top: 52px;
  left: 992px;
}

.fbshare {
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  top: 509px;
  left: 992px;
}

.twshare {
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  top: 546px;
  left: 992px;
}

a {
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.leftcol {
  width: 200px;
  height: 590px;
  float: left;
  background: url("images/lcolb.jpg") no-repeat;
}

.rigcol {
  width: 45px;
  height: 590px;
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 600px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 1030px;
  height: 50px;
}

.learn {
  position: relative;
  top: -58px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #0066cc;
  float: right;
}

.learnT {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.learn:hover {
  background: #3399FF;
}

.learn:hover a {
  color: #fff
}

hr {
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 462px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  border: 0;
}

.Tfind {
  margin-top: 477px;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.Thorizont {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  left: 211px;
  color: white;
}

.hr2 {
  width: 1px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  left: 438px;
  top: 600px;
}

.img1 {
  margin-left: 86px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.img1 {
  margin-left: 46px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.img2 {
  margin-top: 89px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.videocontent {
  width: 785px;
  height: 443px;
  margin-top: 107px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#ModalOpen" title="" onclick="shwoModal();"><img src="images/ban.jpg"></a>

<div id="ModalOpen" class="Window">
  <span>Я внутри модалки(див)</span>
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" id="modal_close" onclick="closeModal();">Х</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Получилось , но теперь проблема возникла в другом , когда закрываешь модалку, обратно на нее зайти не получается< можно зайти только если обновить страничку. в чем ошибка ?

Comment: @andrey, ошибки нет, просто див не отображается у него `display = 'none'` , достаточно сделать  `display = 'block';`

Comment: при этом действии снова не закрывается !

Comment: да , но проблема в том что мне не нужен еще один баттом для открытия , у меня вот эта ссылка  <a href="#ModalOpen" title=""><img src="images/ban.jpg"></a> для открытия модального окна , как быть теперь ?

Comment: Вы можете в этой ссылке прописать `onclick`?