# Как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на крестик, окно закрывалось?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper');
var closse = document.querySelectorAll('.rec');
for (var i = 0; i<wrappers.length; i++) {
 wrappers[i].onclick = function() {
   this.firstElementChild.style.display = 'block';
    rec[i].onclick = function() {
     
    }
  };
};
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.some {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.rec {
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">
    <div class="rec"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">
    <div class="rec"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">
    <div class="rec"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">
    <div class="rec"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Существует 4 div'a при нажатии на которые они затемняются и на них появляется черточка, как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на черточку затемнение пропадало?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как создать кнопку для закрытия модального окна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645698/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper');
for (var wrap of wrappers) {
  wrap.onclick = function() {
    this.firstElementChild.style.display = 'block';
  };

  wrap.querySelector(".rec").onclick = function() {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    this.closest(".some").style.display = "none";
  };
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.some {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.rec {
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">
    <div class="rec"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">
    <div class="rec"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">
    <div class="rec"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">
    <div class="rec"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не работает, какая-то ошибка.

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi какая какая-то?

Comment: @andreymal http://prntscr.com/huu1al

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi  у меня работает, можно попробовать ещё вот так написать -  `wrap.querySelector(".rec").onclick = function(event)`

Answer (score 0):

Самый банальный способ

```js
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper');
var closse = document.querySelectorAll('.rec');
for (var i = 0; i<wrappers.length; i++) {
 wrappers[i].onclick = function() {
    if (this.firstElementChild.style.display == 'block')
     this.firstElementChild.style.display = 'none'
    else
      this.firstElementChild.style.display = 'block'

  };
};
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.some {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.rec {
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">
    <div class="rec"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">
    <div class="rec"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">
    <div class="rec"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">
    <div class="rec"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Данный способ работает при клике на все окно, а надо что бы работало при клике на крестик. Но проблему я уже решил.